# Text ticker stops on hover and stays like that

Tags: jquery, text, hover

On [Codepen](http://codepen.io/purgeru/pen/uDvsr) the Html ticker on mouse hover stops and than stays like that. it wont start moving when the mouse live of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**this might be easier**

```
var width = $('.ticker-text').width(),
containerwidth = $('.ticker-container').width(),
left = containerwidth;
function tick() {
    if(--left < -width){
        left = containerwidth;
    }
    $(".ticker-text").css("margin-left", left + "px");
    timeout = setTimeout( function() { tick() }, 16);  
}
tick();
$('.mousehover').hover(function(){
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}, function(){
  tick();
});
```

made a pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dwzpd

Comment: np, anytime. glad to help. :D

Answer (score 0):

This should fix what you want:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/djLnw

JS:

```
var width = $('.ticker-text').width(),
    containerwidth = $('.ticker-container').width(),
    left = containerwidth;

function tick() {
    if (--left < -width) {
        left = containerwidth;
    }
    $(".ticker-text").css("margin-left", left + "px");
    timeout = setTimeout(tick, 16);
}

$('.mousehover').mouseenter(function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
});
$('.mousehover').mouseout(function () {
    setTimeout(tick, 16);
});
tick();
```